# The INSERT INTO statement contains an unknown field name

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I'm using the following code to export information from an excel file to an access database. It worked fine last time I used it but ever since I started it up today I've been running into the following issue.

```
Public Sub Export_to_ACCDB()
  Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  dbPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Newdatabase.accdb"
  dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  dbWs = Application.Worksheets("DATABASE").Name
  scn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
  dsh = "[" & Application.ActiveSheet.Name & "$]"
  cn.Open scn
 
  'ssql = "INSERT INTO Database ([Column1],[Column2],[Column3]) "
  ssql = ssql & "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh

  cn.Execute ssql         '<<< The error occurs here
End Sub
```

I get the following error running this code:

> Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':
>
> The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'F12'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again.

I don't have a field name called 'F12' in either my excel file or my access database. I can't seem to figure out what's going on.

- Column headers are written correctly.
- Column headers do not contain spaces or other irregularities.

EDIT:

> Seems like Excel thinks you got a 12th column (maybe by accidentally entering something). Mark column L and delete it @FunThomas

This seemed to be the problem. I had to delete all the columns after the last one which contained the correct fieldname. Now it's working again.

Comment: How many columns are on the sheet?  Is there anything in column L at all?

Comment: 11 columns, K is the last one.

Comment: Is there anything at all in 12?

Comment: Seems like Excel thinks you got a 12th column (maybe by accidentally entering something). Mark column L and delete it

Comment: Alright, that did seem to do the trick. I had to delete all the columns after K. Now it worked. Thank you guys. If one of you could reply the answer then I will mark it as answered.